# How to keep styles while dragging an element?

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

My problem is, I have a draggable element, that has some styling. When i'm dragging it, it doesn't keep all the styles, some of them disappear WHILE the element is being dragged.

Specifically the one I need to keep is box-shadow.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kHuhR/167/)

Standard box-shadow style:

```
.fixed-red-bg {
    box-shadow:10px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

How do I not lose my box shadow while dragging that element? Optionally, is there any other style, that is not lost while dragging, that can be used to mimic a depth effect?

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome and Firefox, when you drop the red box into the drop area, the shadow does appear to remain. However, *while* you are dragging it Chrome will usually drop the shadow. I recall this problem being reported a few years ago but I don't believe it's been resolved?

While someone else may have a suitable fix using css, what you can do is make a semi-transparent .png image as the shadow, and position it under the object using the pseudo `before`

Comment: Just edited the question to reinforce the problem happens while dragging. That's a neat suggestion, I'll give that a go and post an update here